# C - Help understanding pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory

I read over [this page](http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-pointers-arrays) about the relationship between arrays and pointers, and it clarified a lot of things but I'm still a bit confused. The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i, classes[6],sum = 0;
  printf("Enter 6 numbers:\n");
  for(i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
  {
  // (classes + i) is equivalent to &classes[i]
  scanf("%d",(classes + i));

  // *(classes + i) is equivalent to classes[i]
  sum += *(classes + i);


}
  printf("Sum = %d", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

So from my understanding this code reads in 6 integers, and then stores each integer in a memory address (classes+i). It then prints out the sum of values at each memory address *(classes + i). This all makes sense but why exactly do the values need to be stored into (classes + i) in the first place? What is it accomplishing by doing this? Thanks for any help, I'm trying hard to fully understand this stuff.

Comment: `why exactly do the values need to be stored` there is no reason, only to show you example how values can be stored at different indexes of array

Comment: You seem to understand exactly what the code does. To understand *why* someone made code to do that, you'd have to ask whoever wrote it. You can look at `printf("moose");` as thoroughly as you want and you won't figure out why I wrote code to print "moose".

Comment: if you mean "why do you have to do this get the sum of 6 `int`s?". The answer is, you don't. You could simply loop through, add each entered value to `sum`, then print out sum at the end. Unless you're going to need access to the individual values outside of the `for` loop, there's no practical reason for storing them.

Answer (score 3):

> why exactly do the values need to be stored into (classes + i) in the first place?

True, that doesn't need to be that. The purpose was to illustrate the relation between pointer and array as you already got in the comment:

```
scanf("%d",(classes + i)); // (classes + i) is equivalent to &classes[i]
```

However, for the task itself (ie calculating the sum), `(classes+i)` is not needed. It'd be simpler to just use a single variable.

```
int i,v,sum = 0;
printf("Enter 6 numbers:\n");
for(i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    scanf("%d",&v);
    sum += v;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Being confused about this is nothing to be ashamed of. The C programming language was poorly designed. The treatment of pointers and array in C is inept. Good coders work around this by using rational coding constructs, such as the ones commented out in your example.

Just because C allows you to do

```
* (classes + i) 
i [classes]
classes [i]
```

doesn't mean you have to use any variant other than the last one.

> This all makes sense but why exactly do the values need to be stored into (classes + i) in the first place?

They don't need to be. This could have been done using a single integer. The code could have done something like

```
int value ; 
. . . . 
scanf("%d", &value);

sum += value ;
```

> What is it accomplishing by doing this?

This appears to be a purely instructional program to illustrate C tricks.

Answer (score 0):

> why exactly do the values need to be stored into `(classes + i)` in the first place?

This is because when you declare an array `int classes[6]`, here `classes` acts as pointer the base address i.e, `&classes[0]` and when you apply arithmetic operations on a pointer, then pointer arithmetic takes place. For example:

```
//pointer arithmetic
classes + i = base_address + (i * sizeof classes)

//hence
classes = &classes[0]
classes + 1 = &classes[1]
classes + 2 = &classes[2]
//so on.....
```

Now, these addresses can be sent into `scanf()` as arguments to store a particular value at a particular array of index. This is just one of the ways of storing elements into array.